# angular-cli 1.5 generated directory structure not working when a different src dir is specified

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have posted an issue to the angular-cli repo with all the details:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8417

Do anyone know a workaround or a fix for this.

---

Thank you

Shyam Sreenivasan

Comment: Did you changed `.angular-cli.json` 's  `apps.root` property to new src directory.

Comment: I created the project with: ng new appName -sd=src/main/webapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue has been fixed in the latest build of angular-cli.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8417

Thank You.